# How to install scipy module installation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I'm trying to install scipy 0.19 for python 3.6 windows 10 32 bit version. I tried the pip installation method but it doesn't work then i also downloaded the .whl file for scipy then also the program shows that "no module named scipy". How do I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: What is your error when you try installing the module via pip?

Comment: quite a big one

Comment: Can you please update your question with it?

Comment: i have added a image showing the error

Comment: You have added the error when installing the wheel. What is the error when you install with PIP?